# Redirection in an ajax called page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have read quite a bit and I still am missing something.

I have a page that has a button on it.  When you click the button it will call an AJAX function that will then wait and refresh every 5 seconds in waiting for a MySQL database change.  Once the change in the database is made, I would like to take the user to a new page all together.

I have tested the refreshing for the database changes and they work great with echos.  I have tried to use windows.location and the php header redirect.  Neither are working.

I am not using jquery for the ajax call.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

code:
index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array(
'player' => 0
);

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="join"><button type="button" onclick="startGame()">Throwdown!</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

rpsjoin.php

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
session_start();

$lastId_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT MAX(id) AS id from game'));
$lastId = $lastId_q['id'];
$gameStatus_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT game.game_status FROM game WHERE game.id =' . $lastId));
$gameStatus = $gameStatus_q['game_status'];



if ($gameStatus == 2) {
  mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO game (game_status, player1_joined) VALUES(1,1)");
  $_SESSION['player'] = '1';
  $playerNumber = $_SESSION['player'];
  $lastId_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT MAX(id) AS id from game'));
  $lastId = $lastId_q['id'];
  $_SESSION['lastId'] = $lastId;
} elseif ($gameStatus == 1 && $_SESSION['player'] != 1) {
  mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE game SET player2_joined = 1 WHERE id = " . $lastId);
  $_SESSION['player'] = '2';
  $playerNumber = $_SESSION['player'];
  $_SESSION['lastId'] = $lastId;
}

$player1_join_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT player1_joined FROM game WHERE game.id =' . $lastId));
$player2_join_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,'SELECT player2_joined FROM game WHERE game.id =' . $lastId));
$player1_join = $player1_join_q['player1_joined'];
$player2_join = $player2_join_q['player2_joined'];

echo $lastId . "<BR>";
echo $gameStatus . "<BR>";
echo $player1_join . "<BR>";
echo $player2_join . "<BR>";

if ($player1_join == 1 && $player1_join == $player2_join) {
  echo '<form action="rpsover.php" method="post">

  <button type="submit" name="player" value="1">Rock</button>
  <button type="submit" name="player" value="2">Paper</button>
  <button type="submit" name="player" value="3">Scissors</button>

  </form>';

 } else {
   echo "Locating player.  Please be patient";
 }

 echo session_id();

 ?>

function startGame() {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("join").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  setTimeout('startGame()',1000);
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","rpsjoin.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

At the end of rpsjoin.php, instead of showing a form, i want to be redirected to another page.

Yes I know my code is bad and there are test echos in it.

Thank you

Comment: In what way is this setup not working?

Comment: Perhaps : document.location.href="yourPage.html"

Comment: @APerson it doesn't redirect to another page.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin Where would I put that line?  Echo it in the PHP?  All the pages I am working with are PHP.

Comment: would you please attach your code.

Comment: Code is attached.  2 more files to go with this, but I didn't know if they were needed to show.  Let me know if you need them.